# bash shell in Cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

when I am in a Cygwin terminal, I can easily use the "source" command.

For example, let's say I have a file called "my_aliases.sh", that contains the following

```
#!/bin/bash -f
alias clear='cmd /c cls'
#unalias clear
```

Then on the Cygwin terminal, I can type

```
$source my_aliases.sh
```

And it just works fine, and whenever I type "clear", I can see that it works.

But I don't know why doing the same thing inside another shell script, and calling that shell script doesn't work.

For example, let's say that I have a file called "run_alias.sh", with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
#
a=`source my_aliases.sh`
b=`ls -ltr`
echo $a
echo $b
```

And when I try to run my file

```
$ ./run_alias.sh
```

It just doesn't do anything. For example, I can see that the command (b) takes place, but nothing happens for command (a).

But after I run "run_alias.sh", and type "clear", I get the following error:

```
$ clear
bash: clear: command not found
```

I even tried to change run_alias.sh as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
echo `source my_aliases.sh`
```

But now when run run_alias.sh, and type clear, I get the exact same error message !!!

Any idea how to call the "source" command from some other shell script in Cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

A child process cannot alter its parent's environment.

When you execute the run_alias.sh script, you launch a new bash process, which sources your alias file. Then the script ends, that bash process terminates and it takes its modified environment with it.

If you want your aliases to be automatically available, source it from your $HOME/.bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks create a subshell. The changes made to your environment in that subshell do not affect the calling environment.

Id you want your script (`run_alias.sh`) to have access to the environment in `my_aliases.sh`, call `source` directly.

```
source my_aliases.sh
b=`ls -lrt`
echo $b
```

and if you want the changes that `run_alias.sh` makes to its environment to propagate to it's parent, run `source` on the command line.

```
$ source run_alias.sh
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation. It makes sense. The problem that I am having is that I have some MAKE files that I am trying to call some shell scripts from, and some of these shell scripts use "source" inside the script, and I was just trying to get around this issue. But even trying to calling a shell script in a MAKEFILE still poses the same problem of calling a subnet. Is there anyway to get around this problem?